# Уведомления, андроид разработка

Tags: android, android-sdk, firebase

Есть GPS система, которая следит за транспортом. Разрабатываем моб. приложение для водителей, GPS система по тригерру должна отправить уведомление на приложение водителю. В андроид разработке новичок, реализовал через firebase, но мне почему то это не нравиться, какие есть еще варианты подскажите пожалуйста? Можно ли сделать, что бы служба в приложении слушала порт сервера(ip статичен) откуда идут уведомления или это будет сильно жрать АКБ?

Comment: Что говорит ваш бэк? Есть ли он? Лучше решение это ВэбСоккеты. Если бэка нет, фаербэйз вам в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент ничего лучше **firebase** нет.
Можно написать свой велосипед и сделать фоновый сервис(службу) который будет делать запрос и проверять статус, но тут много нюансов(основные из-за того что гугл борется с кастомными сервисами, что бы они не были в фоне вечно) и я не думаю что удастся добиться хорошей стабильности в работе на всём зоопарке устройств. Хорошо написанный сервис АКБ жрать не будет(если конечно биткоины не майнить).